# How to convert integers in arrays to floats in python?

Tags: python, arrays

The question I got was this:

Create a 3 x 6-dimensional array, containing only float values.

So my solution was this:

```
import numpy as np


data = np.array([(1,2,3,4,5,6),(1,2,3,4,5,6),(1,2,3,4,5,6)])

data
```

I've tried using float(data), np.float(data) but they don't seem to work.

How do I convert them to floats or is there another way to solve this question? What's the limitations on the float function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data.astype(float)` should do what you need.

```
>>> data = np.array([(1,2,3,4,5,6),(1,2,3,4,5,6),(1,2,3,4,5,6)])
>>> data.astype(float)
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.]])
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you also know how to extract and print 2 rows at the same time? Let's say row 2 and 3. Typing data[1,2] extracts the element

Comment: @JeromeYue: if it worked – you should [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @Azat Ibrakov sorry. Am new to stack overflow

Comment: @JeromeYue you can simply do `print(data[1],data[2])` to print 2nd and 3rd rows, notice python is 0-indexed.
@AzatIbrakov ty!